# Can what be used for people

Tags: pronouns

In the sentence given below

> It would be well for us to admire **what** is worthy of admiration in such a people, rather than to carp about their errors.

I think the reference is made to some of the people who arr worthy of admiration, then why **what** is used. I think it should be **who**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this sentence, "what" **doesn't** actually refer to the people themselves, but to **something about them** (most likely some element or elements of their character) that is worthy of admiration. That is why "what" is used, and is correct.